# Alternate option for cache : false in state provider

Tags: angularjs, html, caching

I have used cache:false in my state to avoid templates(html view) caching like below.

```
.state('index.project_setup', {
        url: '/:customerTag/project-setup',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/common/customer/projects/setup_projects_wizard.html',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Project Setup' },
        cache: false
    })
```

After applying changes in to html file, sometimes i need to hard refresh the page instead of just reload. So is it something i am missing or is there any way to accomplish this thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Angular template caching and your browser caching.
When Angular loads a template for the first time, it will fire an AJAX request for that template, and then store the HTMLin a service called `$templateCache`, so if the exact same template is required again, it will skip the AJAX call and will use the HTML stored in `$templateCache`.

Once you refreshed your page, the `$templateCache` service is initialized (because all the JS is initialized) and all the cached HTMLs are gone, so again when Angular will require an HTML file for a template, it will fire AJAX call the first time, store it in the `$templateCache` and then will use the cached HTML from here on out.

Your browser on the other hand, does not "initialize" his cache on every refresh, so if you will request a file that was cached before, the browser will skip the HTTP call and will use his cached version if one is available.

So lets say we need template named `x.html`, what will happen is the following pseudo code:

```
if (x.html exists in $templateCache)
    return x.html from $templateCache
else
    AngularJS perform HTTP GET for x.html
    if (browser has x.html cached version)
        return x.html from browser cache and don't fire HTTP request
    else
        fire HTTP request for x.html and return the result
```

That is way you must "hard reload" your templates every once in a while.

My solution for development, is attaching a changing query string to the template URL, for example:

```
.state('index.project_setup', {
        url: '/:customerTag/project-setup',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/common/customer/projects/setup_projects_wizard.html?v=' + Date.now(),
        data: { pageTitle: 'Project Setup' },
        cache: false
    })
```

That is a simple trick that causes the browser to always fetch the HTML file because the query string is never the same (well, it will be the same for 1 millisecond :)), so every time the browser will get an HTTP request for that HTML, it will not match previous requests and will not use the cache.